# Flutter | How to click square image from camera and display square image

Tags: flutter, dart, camera, flutter-layout

Here I am working with one project where I need to click an image from the camera and preview it in another screen. so I've done it. but there is some issue here I need to click square image and display also the square image I've tried lots of solutions but it won't work. hope you understand the question. please help me. your little help can make my day.

Here is my code.

```
availableCameras().then((availableCameras) {
  cameras = availableCameras;

  if (cameras.length > 0) {
    setState(() {
      selectedCameraIdx = 0;
    });

    _initCameraController(cameras[selectedCameraIdx]).then((void v) {});
  } else {
    print("No camera available");
  }
}).catchError((err) {
  print('Error: $err.code\nError Message: $err.message');
});
//---------------------------------------------------------------------
    AspectRatio(
          aspectRatio: 1,
          child: ClipRect(
            child: Transform.scale(
              scale: 1 / controller.value.aspectRatio,
              child: Center(
                child: AspectRatio(
                  aspectRatio: controller.value.aspectRatio,
                  child: CameraPreview(controller),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        )
```

This is for Display image

```
Image.file(
   File(widget.imagePath),
 )
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I hope , This is the suitable answer as you wanted.

Plugins: [camera](https://pub.dev/packages/camera), [image_cropper](https://pub.dev/packages/image_cropper)

Run this code:

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:camera/camera.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:image_cropper/image_cropper.dart';
import 'package:path/path.dart' show join;
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';

Future<void> main() async {
  // Ensure that plugin services are initialized so that `availableCameras()`
  // can be called before `runApp()`
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  // Obtain a list of the available cameras on the device.
  final cameras = await availableCameras();

  // Get a specific camera from the list of available cameras.
  final firstCamera = cameras.first;

  runApp(
    MyApp(firstCamera: firstCamera,)
  );
}



class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  final firstCamera;
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  MyApp({this.firstCamera});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      // routes: routes,
       home: TakePictureScreen(
        // Pass the appropriate camera to the TakePictureScreen widget.
        camera: firstCamera,
      ),
   );
  }
}


// A screen that allows users to take a picture using a given camera.
class TakePictureScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  final CameraDescription camera;

  const TakePictureScreen({
    Key key,
    @required this.camera,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  TakePictureScreenState createState() => TakePictureScreenState();
}

class TakePictureScreenState extends State<TakePictureScreen> {
  CameraController _controller;
  Future<void> _initializeControllerFuture;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    // To display the current output from the Camera,
    // create a CameraController.
    _controller = CameraController(
      // Get a specific camera from the list of available cameras.
      widget.camera,
      // Define the resolution to use.
      ResolutionPreset.medium,
    );
    // Next, initialize the controller. This returns a Future.
    _initializeControllerFuture = _controller.initialize();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    // Dispose of the controller when the widget is disposed.
    _controller.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final size = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text('Take a picture')),
      // Wait until the controller is initialized before displaying the
      // camera preview. Use a FutureBuilder to display a loading spinner
      // until the controller has finished initializing.
      body: Center(
        child: Container(
          width: size,
          height: size,
          child: ClipRect(
            child: OverflowBox(
              alignment: Alignment.center,
              child: FittedBox(
                fit: BoxFit.fitWidth,
                child: Container(
                  width: size,
                  height:size,
                  child:FutureBuilder<void>(
                    future: _initializeControllerFuture,
                    builder: (context, snapshot) {
                      if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
                        // If the Future is complete, display the preview.
                        return CameraPreview(_controller);
                      } else {
                        // Otherwise, display a loading indicator.
                        return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
                      }
                    },
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        )
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        child: Icon(Icons.camera_alt),
        // Provide an onPressed callback.
        onPressed: () async {
          // Take the Picture in a try / catch block. If anything goes wrong,
          // catch the error.
          try {
            await _controller.takePicture().then((value) {
              Navigator.push(
              context,
              MaterialPageRoute(
                builder: (context) => DisplayPictureScreen(imagePath: value.path),
              ),
            );

            });
          } catch (e) {
            // If an error occurs, log the error to the console.
            print(e);
          }
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}

// A widget that displays the picture taken by the user.
class DisplayPictureScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  final String imagePath;

  const DisplayPictureScreen({Key key, this.imagePath}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _DisplayPictureScreenState createState() => _DisplayPictureScreenState();
}

class _DisplayPictureScreenState extends State<DisplayPictureScreen> {
  var  finalImage ;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
   
    croppingImage();
  }


  croppingImage()async{
    File croppedFile = await ImageCropper.cropImage(
      sourcePath: File(widget.imagePath).path,
      aspectRatioPresets: [
        CropAspectRatioPreset.square,
        CropAspectRatioPreset.ratio3x2,
        CropAspectRatioPreset.original,
        CropAspectRatioPreset.ratio4x3,
        CropAspectRatioPreset.ratio16x9
      ],
    
      androidUiSettings: AndroidUiSettings(
          toolbarTitle: 'Cropper',
          toolbarColor: Colors.pink,
          toolbarWidgetColor: Colors.white, 
          initAspectRatio: CropAspectRatioPreset.original,
          lockAspectRatio: false),
      iosUiSettings: IOSUiSettings(
        minimumAspectRatio: 1.0,
      )
    );
    if(croppedFile!=null){
      setState(() {
        finalImage = croppedFile;
      });
    }else{
     setState(() {
        finalImage = File(widget.imagePath);
     });
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text('Display the Picture')),
      // The image is stored as a file on the device. Use the `Image.file`
      // constructor with the given path to display the image.
      body: Center(
        child: 
        finalImage !=null ?
        Container(
           height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height/2, //400
          //  width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width/1.2,//400
           decoration: BoxDecoration(
             border: Border.all(color: Colors.red),
             image: DecorationImage(
               image: FileImage(finalImage),
               fit: BoxFit.cover
              )
           ),
        )
        :Container()
      )
    );
  }
}
```

Modify with your AndroidManifest.xml with this

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.myapp">
    
    <!-- io.flutter.app.FlutterApplication is an android.app.Application that
         calls FlutterMain.startInitialization(this); in its onCreate method.
         In most cases you can leave this as-is, but you if you want to provide
         additional functionality it is fine to subclass or reimplement
         FlutterApplication and put your custom class here. -->
         
    <application
        android:name="io.flutter.app.FlutterApplication"
        android:label="myapp"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

          <!-Add Crop Activity -->
           <!-Add this line -->
        <activity
            android:name="com.yalantis.ucrop.UCropActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar"/>

        <!-- Don't delete the meta-data below.
             This is used by the Flutter tool to generate GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="flutterEmbedding"
            android:value="2" />
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Camera View in Square shape:

[image]

Cropping captured image before showing:

[image]

Captured image in Square view:

[image]

Comment: I appreciate your answer but this camera result is display square but is this being the same when I upload this picture on the server. I mean is it the same result also on the server or it will be default ratio?

Comment: Okay then use [image_cropper](https://pub.dev/packages/image_cropper) plugin before showing and uploading image.

Comment: do you have any example of it?

Comment: tap on [image_cropper](https://pub.dev/packages/image_cropper), and read ReadMe ,it has example of plugin or give me some min ,i'll implement it my code and will show you

Comment: Hello, Sorry for late. I was stuck in other project. BTW I have implemented cropped functionality , you may check my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

You should use image cropper for this feature. when you take image from camera or gallery just crop image through this : https://pub.dev/packages/image_cropper